# Programmatically set the type of file to read with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a script that should take as input a file, read it into a pandas dataframe, and do some stuff. I would have liked not to force the file to be in a specific format, and leave the user tell the script how it should read it. However, I don't seem to find any support for this. Is it possible? Or should I do it manually? Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you think user decide dtype of column  - int, float or str?

Comment: No, I mean to say if the file is in csv or xls or pickle or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
filename = "userprovided.csv"

mapping = {
    'csv': pd.read_csv,
    'xlsx': pd.read_excel,
    ...
}

ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

data = mapping[ext](filename)
```

Of course there needs to be some error checking etc.

Comment: That was my backup plan indeed, but I was wondering if there was some built in way to do this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be

Comment: Oh well I'll just roll with it then, I wanted to be sure before thanks